# How to apply a ":contains" selector without jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am looking to be able to do this function

```
$( "div:contains('John')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

without using jQuery, just straight up javascript, I cant find the equivalent

I know I am looking for `indexOf`, but putting it all together is not working for my current mindset.

Comment: you're looking for something like `getElementByID()`, right?!

Comment: I am looking to find a list item that has the word "Music" in it, and change its css styling `<li><a class="btn" href="http://url.here">Music</a></li>`

Comment: *"...without using jQuery, just straight up javascript..."* jQuery ***is*** "straight up JavaScript." What you mean is, "without a library, just using the DOM."

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/ -- this is the jQuery page refrenced -- and yes @T.J.Crowder, thank you

Comment: I would normally suggest looking at the library code to see how it does it. But [jQuery's implementation](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/5d5ea015114092c157311c4948f7cc3d8c8e7f8a/src/selector.js#L860) is pretty difficult to understand.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
var divs= document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var len = divs.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(divs[i].innerHTML.indexOf("John") != -1) {
        divs[i].className += " underline"
    }
}
```

and in css

```
.underline{
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably something like thus:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i=0;i<elements.length;i++) {
    var elem = elements[i];
    if (elem.innerHTML.indexOf("John") != -1) {
        // do whatever you plan to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to support modern browsers (and achieve the aims of your posted 'for-translation' code):

```
var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

[].forEach.call(allDivs, function(a){
    if (a.textContent.indexOf('John') !== -1){
        a.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vYHZL/1/).

If you'd prefer it to be case-insensitive, and to avoid matching 'Johnson':

```
var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

[].forEach.call(allDivs, function(a){
    if (/\bjohn\b/i.test(a.textContent)){
        a.style.textDecoration = 'underline';
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vYHZL/2/).

As other answers have demonstrated, it's better to avoid styling the element(s) directly, and instead rely in usage of CSS class-names to style the elements, that way *un*-styling doesn't require unsetting individual properties of the `Node.style` object. To add classes, using the above approach (again for up-to-date browsers):

```
var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

[].forEach.call(allDivs, function(a){
    if (/\bjohn\b/i.test(a.textContent)){
        a.classList.add('underlined');
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vYHZL/4/).

To highlight only, and all instances of, the name 'John' (or 'john'):

```
var allDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div');

[].forEach.call(allDivs, function (a) {
    if (/\bjohn\b/gi.test(a.textContent)) {
        a.innerHTML = a.innerHTML.replace(/(\bjohn\b)/gi, '<span class="underlined">$1</span>');
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vYHZL/5/).

References:

- [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.classList).
- [`Function.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions).
- [`Regexp.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Ftest).

Comment: very thorough explanation and I will look at each one more fully on Monday (when back at work)... just wanted to thank you for all of the thought you put into it while I have it open!

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, and I'm glad to have been of (some) help.

Comment: What does attaching `forEach` to an empty array ( `[]` ) do?

Answer (score 1):

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (i in tags) {
    var tag = tags[i];
    if (tag && tag.innerHTML && tag.innerHTML.indexOf('John') > -1) {
        // Your tag!
        console.log(tag);
    }
}
```