# Highlight current day on a <div> table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I am trying to highlight the current day in a `<Div>` table (using css and jQuery) but can't wrap my head around it (I don't want to use php because it must be dynamic)

This is part of what I have done.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1'>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../themes/images/logo-180x178-52.png" type="image/x-icon">
  <link rel="STYLESHEET" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.0.min.css" />
  <link rel="STYLESHEET" href="../themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
  <title>Rooster week 15</title>
  <style>
    .rTable {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .rTableRow {
      display: table-row;
    }
    .rTableHeading {
      display: table-header-group;
      background-color: orange;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .rTableBody {
      display: table-row-group;
    }
    .rTableFoot {
      display: table-footer-group;
      font-weight: bold;
      background-color: orange;
    }
    .rTableCell,
    .rTableHead {
      display: table-cell;
    }
    .cZondag {
      display: table-row;
      background-color: lightgreen;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .cMaandag {
      display: table-row;
      background-color: lightgreen;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    //.cDinsdag { display: table-row; background-color: lightgreen; font-weight: bold;}
    //.cWoensdag { display: table-row; background-color: lightgreen; font-weight: bold;}
    //.cDonderdag { display: table-row; background-color: lightgreen; font-weight: bold;}
    //.cVrijdag { display: table-row; background-color: lightgreen; font-weight: bold;}
    //.cZaterdag { display: table-row; background-color: lightgreen; font-weight: bold;}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var d = new Date();
      var weekday = new Array(7);
      weekday[0] = "Zondag";
      weekday[1] = "Maandag";
      weekday[2] = "Dinsdag";
      weekday[3] = "Woensdag";
      weekday[4] = "Donderdag";
      weekday[5] = "Vrijdag";
      weekday[6] = "Zaterdag";

      var n = weekday[d.getDay()];
      var nTable = document.getElementById('maandag');
      // document.write(nTable); // debugging only

    }
    myFunction()
  </script>

  <h1>Rooster Week 15</h1> Richard van Soest
  <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="week14.htm" data-icon="calendar">Vorige week</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="week16.htm" data-icon="calendar" class="ui-btn-active">Volgende week</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="geheim.php" data-icon="lock">Sleutels</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <p>
    </p>
    <div class="rTable">
      <div class="rTableHeading">
        <div class="rTableHead">Dag</div>
        <div class="rTableHead"></div>
        <div class="rTableHead">Route</div>
        <div class="rTableHead">Aanvang</div>
        <div class="rTableHead">Duur</div>
      </div>
      <div class="rTableBody">
        <div class="rTableRow" id="maandag">
          <div class="rTableCell">11-04</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">Maandag</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">EX 3</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">15:15</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">3:30</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableRow" id="dinsdag">
          <div class="rTableCell">12-04</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">Dinsdag</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">EX 3</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">15:15</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">3:30</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableRow" id="woensdag">
          <div class="rTableCell">13-04</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">Woensdag</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">EX 3</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">15:15</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">3:30</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableRow" id="donderdag">
          <div class="rTableCell">14-04</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">Donderdag</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">EX 3</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">15:15</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">3:30</div>
        </div>
        <div class="rTableRow" id="vrijdag">
          <div class="rTableCell">15-04</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">Vrijdag</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">EX 3</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">15:15</div>
          <div class="rTableCell">3:30</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="rTableFoot">
        <div class="rTableHead">Totaal</div>
        <div class="rTableHead"></div>
        <div class="rTableHead"></div>
        <div class="rTableHead"></div>
        <div class="rTableHead">14:00</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" role="banner" class="ui-header ui-bar-inherit">
      <a href="tel:081111111" data-icon="phone" data-theme="c" class="ui-link ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-c ui-icon-phone ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-role="button" role="button">Control</a>
      <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">who you gonne call</h1>
      <a href="tel:061111111" data-icon="phone" data-theme="d" class="ui-link ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-d ui-icon-phone ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-role="button" role="button">Call CU</a>
    </div>
    <br />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The code is generated by a VBA script in Excel where the data comes from and is uploaded to a server automatically.

It is supposed to be running on a phone screen (fullscreen)

Comment: Start by wrapping your call so the table exists: `window.onload=function() {   myFunction(); }` - Also right now all I see is a circle on the screen - the Snippet does not understand your relative paths. Also you have no jQuery in your script

Comment: If it only needs to highlight the current day, how does it need to be "dynamic"? PHP might be the easiest way to do this.

Comment: Dynamic in a way it don't need a page refresh to show the current date

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for the help (btw without jquery it does NOT work)

Comment: It could: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059778/how-to-apply-a-contains-selector-without-jquery

Comment: Ok saw that, but i am using jquery mobile to make the page look good on a mobile (i used bootstrap before but an other link in my page is not getting the right look after loading, But after refreshing it looks right.) I think its a cash problem, thats why i am make use of same styles and libraries on booth pages) (layout is folowing on my agenda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note my code will only highlight when the table contains a date around now.

```js
function pad(num) {
  return String("0"+num).slice(-2);
}
$(function() {
  var d = new Date(); // test with new Date(2016,3,14); JS months start at 0
  var ddmm = ""+pad(d.getDate())+"-"+pad(d.getMonth()+1);
  $(".rTableRow:contains('"+ddmm+"')").addClass("highlight");
});
```

```css
.highlight { background-color:red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Rooster Week 15</h1> Richard van Soest
<div data-role="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="week14.htm" data-icon="calendar">Vorige week</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="week16.htm" data-icon="calendar" class="ui-btn-active">Volgende week</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="geheim.php" data-icon="lock">Sleutels</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
  <p>
  </p>
  <div class="rTable">
    <div class="rTableHeading">
      <div class="rTableHead">Dag</div>
      <div class="rTableHead"></div>
      <div class="rTableHead">Route</div>
      <div class="rTableHead">Aanvang</div>
      <div class="rTableHead">Duur</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableBody">
      <div class="rTableRow" id="maandag">
        <div class="rTableCell">11-04</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">Maandag</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">EX 3</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">15:15</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">3:30</div>
      </div>
      <div class="rTableRow" id="dinsdag">
        <div class="rTableCell">12-04</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">Dinsdag</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">EX 3</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">15:15</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">3:30</div>
      </div>
      <div class="rTableRow" id="woensdag">
        <div class="rTableCell">13-04</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">Woensdag</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">EX 3</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">15:15</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">3:30</div>
      </div>
      <div class="rTableRow" id="donderdag">
        <div class="rTableCell">14-04</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">Donderdag</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">EX 3</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">15:15</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">3:30</div>
      </div>
      <div class="rTableRow" id="vrijdag">
        <div class="rTableCell">15-04</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">Vrijdag</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">EX 3</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">15:15</div>
        <div class="rTableCell">3:30</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="rTableFoot">
      <div class="rTableHead">Totaal</div>
      <div class="rTableHead"></div>
      <div class="rTableHead"></div>
      <div class="rTableHead"></div>
      <div class="rTableHead">14:00</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" role="banner" class="ui-header ui-bar-inherit">
    <a href="tel:081111111" data-icon="phone" data-theme="c" class="ui-link ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-btn-c ui-icon-phone ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-role="button" role="button">Control</a>
    <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">who you gonne call</h1>
    <a href="tel:061111111" data-icon="phone" data-theme="d" class="ui-link ui-btn-right ui-btn ui-btn-d ui-icon-phone ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-role="button" role="button">Call CU</a>
  </div>
  <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks i added your function to the html and it turns the div from monday red, so it looks like it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure What is Current date field, so I assume that it is a first record. you can do it without jquery. below are code sample

```
/*Only work hover over element*/
 .rTableRow > div:first-child:hover{
background-color:red; }



 /* work all the time*/
 .rTableRow > div:first-child{
background-color:red;  }
```

Comment: sorry this is not what i meant